# Want to show all data values under its group with title in CGridview in yii

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions, cgridview

I want to show the following list in CGridview in yii

[image]

OR
I want the result like the following image[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use this nice extension: http://groupgridview.demopage.ru/index.php?r=site/extrarow